# CX_Oracle insert data using Bind variable / function and return the record id too

Tags: python, cx-oracle

I am trying to create a definition using cx_oracle to insert data in to the database and in return get the record id. I searched the forum and found the solution as below.

```
def insert_data(self,SqlQry):
     try:
         idvar=self.__cursor.var(cx_Oracle.NUMBER)
         SqlQry=SqlQry + " returning ID into :vrecord_id"

         self.__cursor.execute(SqlQry,v1='test1',v2='test2',v3='test3',v4='test4', vrecord_id=idvar)
         vid= idvar.getvalue()
         self.__con.commit()
         retuen vid    

     except cx_Oracle.DatabaseError as e:
         return e
         print("Error in data insert")  


print(sql_insertData("INSERT INTO MYTABLE(Field1,Field2,Field3,Field4) VALUES(:v1, :v2, :v3,:v4)")
```

This works fine and i am able to get the ID. But i want to pass the values with the sql statement inplace of defining each individually as i have done now in .execute line.

```
cursor.execute(SqlQry,v1='test1',v2='test2',v3='test3',v4='test4', vrecord_id=idvar)
```

I want to change the current print statement to like this :

```
print(sql_insertData(
        """INSERT INTO RAP_RISK_TYPE(RISK_HEADER,RISK_TYPE_DISP,RISK_TYPE_DESC,RISK_TYPE_CAT) 
           VALUES
           (:v1, :v2, :v3,:v4)""", ['newvalue1','newvalue2','newvalue3','newvalue4']
```

But if i do this how do i write the execute statement to get the ID, i get error if i do the below

```
def insert_data(self,SqlQry,parm):
        try:
            idvar=self.__cursor.var(cx_Oracle.NUMBER)
            SqlQry=SqlQry + " returning ID into :vrecord_id"

            self.__cursor.execute(SqlQry,parm, vrecord_id=idvar)
            vid= idvar.getvalue()
            self.__con.commit()
            retuen vid    

        except cx_Oracle.DatabaseError as e:
            return e
            print("Error in data insert")  


print(sql_insertData(
        """INSERT INTO RAP_RISK_TYPE(RISK_HEADER,RISK_TYPE_DISP,RISK_TYPE_DESC,RISK_TYPE_CAT) 
           VALUES
           (:v1, :v2, :v3,:v4)""", ['newvalue1','newvalue2','newvalue3','newvalue4']
```

I am not able to pass the list from the print statement and add the "idvar" both at same time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With cx_Oracle 7.3, you can access [`Cursor.lastRowid`](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api_manual/cursor.html#Cursor.lastrowid) after executing the INSERT.  See the cx_Oracle example [`LastRowid.py`](https://github.com/oracle/python-cx_Oracle/blob/master/samples/LastRowid.py):

```
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("insert into mytab (id, data) values (:1, :2)", [1, "First"])
print("Rowid 1:", cursor.lastrowid)
```

Otherwise use the RETURNING INTO clause you were looking at.  There is a RETURNING INTO example at https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/bind.html#dml-returning-bind-variables.

Comment: The ROWID pseudocolumn returns the address of the row (which is not the IDENTITY value of the Primary Key of the new record).
Please refer to the manual: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns008.htm.

Answer (score 1):

Chris has given an excellent generic answer. If you are looking for the specific answer to your question, you need to do the following:

```
self.__cursor.execute(SqlQry, parm + [idvar])
```

In other words, you need to ensure that only one set of parameters is passed, not multiple!